# Correcting for sample size in skewed data

Tags: descriptive-statistics, quantiles, skewness

Empirically I have noticed that when data is skewed, and when for example interested in the 99th percentile of latencies, that it is difficult to compare experiments with different sample sizes

Imagine I run an experiment for 500 iterations and then afterwards for 2000 iterations, then the p99 when iter=2000 is simply higher

This is example descriptives data:

```
count    583.0000000000
mean     810.3430531732
std     1472.5106312310
min      112.0000000000
1%       166.6400000000
10%      234.0000000000
25%      274.5000000000
50%      373.0000000000
75%      779.5000000000
90%     1575.0000000000
99%     7404.4400000000
max    16479.0000000000
```

How can I make this data comparable between experiments correcting for the sample size? Is there some formula?

Comment: Well, this seems to be more of an issue with you having skewed (and maybe some "outlying") data, which keeps changing the "extreme" quantiles much more than the central ones, which makes sense. The solution then is to just use more data so that even these quantiles stabilize.

Comment: I wonder if there is some kind of theorem about this involving order statistics, perhaps something involving the variance of order statistic $X_{(k)}$ depending on the ratio of $k$ to the sample size.

Comment: Please explain how iteration and sample size are related here. Are they the same thing in your context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to reproduce what you have noticed is difficult without knowing the distribution involved, but using a distribution with $F(x)=1-\frac{100}{x}$ and $f(x)=\frac{100}{x^2}$ for $x> 100$ (a Pareto distribution with shape $\alpha=1$ and minimum $100$) seems to give roughly the same sort of shape which is heavily skewed.

The following R code allows simulation of the $99\%$ quantile samples from this

```
set.seed(2023)
quantile <- 0.99
largersamplesize <- 2000
smallersamplesize <- 500
cases <- 10^4
samplequantile <- function(samplesize, p){
  quantile(100/runif(samplesize), p)
  }
simslarger  <- replicate(cases, samplequantile(largersamplesize,  quantile))
simssmaller <- replicate(cases, samplequantile(smallersamplesize, quantile))
plot(density(simslarger),   col="red")
lines(density(simssmaller), col="blue")
abline(v=100/(1-quantile))
```

with the following empirical densities (red for the larger sample, blue for the smaller sample)

[image]

You can see that the simulated $99\%$ quantiles have wide distributions around the population $99\%$ quantile (the vertical black line), that both distributions are right-skewed, and that the larger sample size leads to greater concentration of the sample quantile.

It is quite possible that the quantile from the smaller sample can be greater than the quantile from the larger sample but, thanks to the skewness, the larger sample quantile is slightly more likely to be larger in a particular case. Using this simulation suggests a probability of about $56.5\%$, though different simulations would produce slightly different estimates.

```
mean(simslarger > simssmaller) # probability larger sample gives higher value
# 0.565 with this seed
```

The effect will be smaller and the concentrations narrower with even larger sample sizes or looking at a less extreme quantile.

Comment: Nice simulation! So is the only way to compare to use approximate same number of samples?

Comment: Even if you had the same sample size in both samples (say 500), the $99\%$ sample quantile could still vary widely as illustrated with the blue density

Comment: Still wondering if we could try some kind of transformation using the probability. For example, given that I want to compare n=200 sample with n=3000 and assuming the same distribution, how could I transform for example the mean or the 60% percentile to the n=3000 example (n=3000 into n=200) - basically I would like a better estimate to compare them rather than just blindly using the sample estimates. Any ideas?

Comment: @PascalVKooten There is no natural transformation for a single sample of size $3000$ to make it more like a sample of size $200$ [or the $2000$ and $500$ in your original question] unless you already know the figure you are aiming for, which would defeat the point of the sampling.  In my simulation example, the theoretical mean for the distribution is infinite, while the distribution of the $99\%$ quantile to be centred around about $\frac{100}{1-0.99}=10000$ for both sample sizes.  The larger sample size makes it more likely you are closer to that central figure but with no guarantee.

Comment: `mean(abs(simslarger-10000) > abs(simssmaller-10000))` in my simulation gives about $0.31$ for the probability the smaller sample size gets closer to $10000$ than the larger sample size does.  If both samples were the same size, this would be $0.5$.  So the problem with an extreme quantile of an extreme skewed distribution is that you need very large sample sizes to do this comparison. If you had looked at the $1\%$ quantile, both would be more concentrated around about $101.01$

Comment: Is there a way to use the empirical sample data (and sample sizes), to make a better guess than naively comparing? Some kind of multiplication of the p99 of small to make it less biased (i.e. move to the right)

Comment: @PascalVKooten If you take the particular simulations from my answer, then `mean(simslarger)` gives about $9959$ and `mean(simssmaller)` gives about $10068$ - if anything then the opposite direction from what you are suggesting, but likely swamped by simulation noise.

Comment: I think this is different  is for the skewed part of the data (p99) rather than the mean

Comment: @PascalVKooten My example distribution has such a heavy tail that its distribution mean is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

There are some nasty cases to think of: some probability distributions with a fat tail have an infinite mean value. One example is $P(X=x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$.

If you are interested in the tail, then big samples become all the more important.